# Why is my increment not being calculated right?

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

I've got a for-loop running, and it asks them for the increment number. But when it outputs the table, it actually doubles the increment. So if I put in `10` for `incr` it will go up by 20. Please help?

```
for (double x = fah1; x <= fah2; x+=incr) {
    double cel = 5/9.0 * (x-32);
    if (x <= 99){
        System.out.println(x + "               " + df.format(cel);
        x+= incr;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(x + "              " + df.format(cel));
        x+=incr;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is incr,fah1 and fah2? there are wierd things happen if you add int and double, or double and double. thats why using <= or == in double are a bad idea. anyway, please post more of your code so we can see

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are incrementing twice per loop, once in either the `if` or `else`, and again at the end in the third statement of the `for` loop declaration.

Remove the increments in the `if` and `else` and rely on the one in the `for` loop declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up removing the x+=incr statement from the for statement, that seemed to do the trick. Any downsides to the way I did it?

Comment: That would work too, but looking at the code, it's less clear.  Usually the increment happens in the `for` loop declaration, and not copied through all execution paths of the body of the loop.

Answer (score 4):

You are incrementing twice - once in the `for` loop declaration and once in the `if-then-else` statement:

Try changing it to this:

```
for (double x = fah1; x <= fah2; x+=incr) {
    double cel = 5/9.0 * (x-32);
    if (x <= 99){
        System.out.println(x + "               " + df.format(cel);
        // Remove the increment from here
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(x + "              " + df.format(cel));
        // Remove the increment from here
    }
}
```